# RxJS - Skip to subscribe

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs

I was wondering if there was a way to cause an observable to skip to the subscribe operator (without terminating). The use case for me is that, I have a 'loginClicked' observable (a subject) where I perform an API call and then subscribe to the next event. The API call is performed using promises and any error I encounter, I wrap in a

```
Promise.resolve(error)
```

so that the observable does not terminate (allowing them to try and login again using the same observable (subject)).

However before I call the API I want to do use

```
doOnNext()
```

to check the internet connectivity. If there IS a connection then continue as normal. However, if there isn't anything, I want to immediately go straight to the onNext callback of subscribe passing in some 'NoConnectivityError'.

Is there anything that will help me solve this or am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
this.loginClickedStream
    .doOnNext(function() {
        if (!connectedToWifi) {
            //Skip to subscribe passing some data somehow
            skipToSubscribe({error: 'NotConnectedToWifi'});
        } 
    })
    .flatMap(function() {
        return fetch(url);
    })
    .subscribe(function(response) {
        if (response.error === 'NotConnectedToWifi') {
         //Show alert
        } else if (response.ok) {
            //Display response in UI
        } else {
            //Show alert showing error
        }
    });
```

Notice how when the user is not connected to wifi the observable is passed directly to the subscribe method. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Could you add a more complete code example of what you have so far? I'm not clear on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I have update the OP, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in flatMap, as following:

```
this.loginClickedStream
    .flatMap(function() {
        if (!connectedToWifi) {
            return Rx.Observable.return({error: 'NotConnectedToWifi'});
        } else {
            return fetch(url);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(function(response) {
        if (response.error === 'NotConnectedToWifi') {
         //Show alert
        } else if (response.ok) {
            //Display response in UI
        } else {
            //Show alert showing error
        }
    });
```